# java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind

Tags: javascript, java, socketexception

I am getting this error when I am trying to run my project in eclipse:

```
Server started. Listening to the port 4444
    java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:359)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:97)
    at MainServer.<init>(MainServer.java:30)
    at MainServer.main(MainServer.java:86)
```

please suggest me some ways to clear this error.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the target port number is already occupied by another application server. 
First, You have to check **any previous server application running** in your eclipse if so, terminate them all.

then you will have a list what port is used or not by command if you are sure to find no server running :

```
netstat -an|grep port-number (*NIX)
```

or

```
netstat -an|findStr port-number (Windows).
```

For example in windows, you will see the port 47001 listening now.

[image]